# ODI Start agent fail

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

When I try to start odi agent with this command:

```
C:\ORACLE_HOME\user_projects\domains\ODIDOMAIN\bin>agent -NAME=OracleDIAgent1 -PORT=20910
```

This error is shown:

```
ODI-1404: Agent OracleDIAgent1 start failure: an authentication error occurred while connecting to the master repository.
Caused by: oracle.odi.core.security.BadCredentialsException: ODI-10199: Incorrect ODI username or password.
the full text is:
2020-11-04 07:17:58.676 NOTIFICATION New data source: [DEV_ODI_REPO/*******@jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.1.5.66:1521/ORCL66]
2020-11-04 07:18:04.599 NOTIFICATION ODI-1128 Agent OracleDIAgent1 is starting. Container: STANDALONE. Agent Version: 12.2.1. Port: 20910. JMX Port: 21910.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Allowing : 127.0.0.1,10.1.5.66,127.0.0.1
2020-11-04 07:18:10.088 WARNING odi.core.security.SecurityManager.loadAuthenticationMode found the authMode:mUsingLDAPAuthentication: false,mUsingIDCSAuthentication:false,indExternalAuth:null.
2020-11-04 07:18:10.420 ERROR ODI-1131 Agent OracleDIAgent1 encountered an error: ODI-1404: Agent OracleDIAgent1 start failure: an authentication error occurred while connecting to the master repository. Caused by: ODI-10199: Incorrect ODI username or password.
2020-11-04 07:18:10.420 WARNING ODI-1404: Agent OracleDIAgent1 start failure: an authentication error occurred while connecting to the master repository.
Caused by: oracle.odi.core.security.BadCredentialsException: ODI-10199: Incorrect ODI username or password.
2020-11-04 07:18:10.435 WARNING unavailable
2020-11-04 07:18:10.435 WARNING Failed startup of context o.o.@17125ea9{/oraclediagent,file:/C:/ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/ODIDOMAIN/system_components/ODI/OracleDIAgent1/work/webapp/,STARTING}{file:/C:/ORACLE_HOME/odi/agent/lib/./oraclediagent.war}
2020-11-04 07:18:10.435 WARNING FAILED o.o.@17125ea9{/oraclediagent,file:/C:/ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/ODIDOMAIN/system_components/ODI/OracleDIAgent1/work/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:/C:/ORACLE_HOME/odi/agent/lib/./oraclediagent.war}: javax.servlet.ServletException: ODI-1404: Agent OracleDIAgent1 start failure: an authentication error occurred while connecting to the master repository.
Caused by: oracle.odi.core.security.BadCredentialsException: ODI-10199: Incorrect ODI username or password.
2020-11-04 07:18:10.471 WARNING FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@77bca6d6: javax.servlet.ServletException: ODI-1404: Agent OracleDIAgent1 start failure: an authentication error occurred while connecting to the master repository.
Caused by: oracle.odi.core.security.BadCredentialsException: ODI-10199: Incorrect ODI username or password.
2020-11-04 07:18:10.472 ERROR ODI-1443 Error while starting agent : ODI-1404: Agent OracleDIAgent1 start failure: an authentication error occurred while connecting to the master repository.
Caused by: oracle.odi.core.security.BadCredentialsException: ODI-10199: Incorrect ODI username or password.
2020-11-04 07:18:10.503 ERROR ODI-1404: Agent OracleDIAgent1 start failure: an authentication error occurred while connecting to the master repository.
Caused by: oracle.odi.core.security.BadCredentialsException: ODI-10199: Incorrect ODI username or password.
2020-11-04 07:18:10.503 ERROR javax.servlet.ServletException: ODI-1404: Agent OracleDIAgent1 start failure: an authentication error occurred while connecting to the master repository.
Caused by: oracle.odi.core.security.BadCredentialsException: ODI-10199: Incorrect ODI username or password.
```

The ODI version is 12 and node manager and weblogic is starting correctly.

Comment: Can you log into ODI Studio with the SUPERVISOR user? From the Topology tab you can review and test the ODIAgent configuration.

Comment: Yes I can login into ODI  with the SUPERVISOR user, but at first I have to execute "agent -NAME=OracleDIAgent1 -PORT=20910" and after that test agent in topology.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, the ODI username or password that was provided when configuring the agent is incorrect.

To reconfigure the agent and set the correct credentials on Windows :

1. execute config.cmd in C:\ORACLE_HOME\oracle_common\common\bin
2. click next on all the steps except the ODI Server Configuration page where you can type the password
3. start the agent

More info in [Oracle Support Doc ID 2386816.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2386816.1)

Comment: @jermefr Thank you for reply, I ran config.cmd, and choosed update exciting domain on ODI page, I have changed the password but the problem is still remain.

Comment: Are you sure you use the correct username and password?
The user has to have supervisor privileges.

Comment: I use supervisor user that has supervisor privilege.

Comment: Are you respecting the case for user/password? If SUPERVISOR is in upper case, make sure to enter it in upper case.

Comment: Yes, I have checked everything and respecting to case

Comment: @jermefr In "ODI sever configuration" step I use same username and password with supervisor privilege which access to ODI Studio, and there is no problem on that environment,  However, I've changed the SUPERVISOR password on security tab and retyped on   "ODI sever configuration" step, but I got same error.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the problem with `SUPERVISOR` credentials. if you have multiple Agents in various servers you may face this issue. only one agent may fail out of `n`.

Copy the `ODI_MASTER_ENCODED_PASS` value to the expected location within the `odiparams.sh` file on the system where the agent is not starting.
The odiparams.sh file can be found in:

> $ODI_HOME\oracledi\agent\bin